# Dynamic Model Form Fields

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, model, field

I have a model formset. One of the fields in the base model is a charfield. I need this field to carry different choices depending on the form. i.e. Within the formset, some forms will have choices a,b & c and others will have choice e,f and g. Despite reading Django documentation and several Q&A's in stack overflow, I'm still at a loss.

The Django documentation says:

```
Note that choices can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically.
```

However, it does not give an example how to do this. Would be grateful if someone could give me an example.

My model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    budgetcatagory=models.ForeignKey(BudgetCatagory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    enName=models.CharField(max_length=30, default ="")
    detail=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    layout=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="normal")
    unit=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_description=models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    unit_price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    QTY=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    param1=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param2=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param3=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    param4=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent=models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "0")
    cost_ave=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    cost_min=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    cost_max=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    total_cost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects=ItemManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Instances get constructed via the following code in an object manager:

```
def normalCreate(self, cat, parent, name, description, unit, U, enName, Param1, Param2, Layout, min_val, max_val, ave_val):

    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()

    if parent=="פיתוח":
        q=House.objects.get(user_id=U.id).plot_size
    else:
        q=House.objects.get(user_id=U.id).area
    I=self.create(budgetcatagory_id=cat.id, name=name, unit=unit, detail='Low', unit_description=description , parent=parent, QTY=q, unit_price=ave_val, total_cost=ave_val*q, enName=enName, cost_min=min_val, cost_max=max_val, cost_ave=ave_val )
    I.save()
    return I
```

I would like to add some code to normalCreate that would, under certain conditions, create a list of choice for param1, that would render as such in the template. Its important to not that it is not critical for me to perform validation on the choices..

Thanks

Comment: Little confusion here. Why are you using `normalCreate` method? You need to have a form corresponding to your model. And when you are rendering the form, its where you need to render different choice fields dynamically.

Comment: I am using the nor normalCreate method (one of a few cunstruction methods) to create initial form instances in the set, in different ways.